# how can I use GATT_Notification command with BTool

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

im using BTool to send commands to CC2540 bluetooth module. I want to get notifications.  when I send notification command, btool displayed the sent command

```
[43] : <Tx> - 11:11:47.051
-Type           : 0x01 (Command)
-OpCode         : 0xFD9B (GATT_Notification)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) byte(s)
 ConnHandle     : 0x0000 (0)
 Authentic      : 0x00 (0) (No)
 Handle         : 0x1B00 (6912)
 Value          : 00:50
Dump(Tx):
0000:01 9B FD 06 00 00 00 1B 00 50
```

the values of the `Handle` (temperature characteristic) and `connHandle` are correct, but I dont get any response from the server. is there any prior configuration to perform, like enabling notifications somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable notification for the characteristic. First you need to query for the client characteristic configuration uuid:

```
08 1B 00 1C 00 02 29
```

where first byte is the op read request, next two bytes are you handle id, subsequent two bytes are the range limit (handle id + 1), and the last two bytes are the `GATT_CLIENT_CHARAC_CFG_UUID` filter. You'll get a response similar to this:

```
09 04 LL HH 00 00
```

where the first byte is the response (read by type response), next byte is payload length, `LL HH` is the configuration characteristic handle, and the last two bytes are it's value.

At this step you can enable the notification by writing a 0x0001 to this handle id:

```
12 LL HH 01 00
```

At his point the notification for you characteristic should be enabled.